# In which method should I make retrofit calls, if I am using tab layout with three tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, android-tablayout

So I have three tabs and in two of those tabs I have to make retrofit calls.

I have tried calling methods which have retrofit calls in onCreateView method. In onResponse method, I have tried loading image through the url received. But when I am debugging my app, the onCreateView is returning the view, even before onResponse is called.

In which method should I make retrofit calls in fragment ?

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView trailer_thumbnail;
private static final String  preImgUrl = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_fragment, container, false);
    trailer_thumbnail = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trailer_thumbnail);
    updateTrailer();
    /*if( DetailsActivity.movieTrailerList.size() != 0 )
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(preImgUrl + DetailsActivity.movieTrailerList.get(0).getKey() + "/default.jpg").
                placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                into(trailer_thumbnail);*/
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

private void updateTrailer(){
    final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.show();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().
            baseUrl(MainActivity.baseUrl).
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
            build();

    final RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    Call<MovieTrailerResponse> call1 = requestInterface.getMovieTrailers(list.get(index).getId(), MainActivity.apiKEy);

    call1.enqueue(new Callback<MovieTrailerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieTrailerResponse> call, Response<MovieTrailerResponse> response) {

            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            List<MovieTrailer> movieTrailerList = response.body().getResults();
            Log.i("trailer", preImgUrl + movieTrailerList.get(0).getKey() + "/default.jpg");

            if ( movieTrailerList.get(0).getSite() == "YouTube")
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load( preImgUrl + movieTrailerList.get(0).getKey() + "/default.jpg").
                        into(trailer_thumbnail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieTrailerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

This is my tab3 fragment class,when I am debugging the app, `onCreateView` is being called even before trailers tab is being selected and the view is returned, before the api call is receiving the data. So I am unable to load the image even with progressdialog. In fact progress dialog is showing when I select tab2.

Comment: It depends up on your requirement.`But when I am debugging my app, the onCreateView is returning the view, even before onResponse is called` . What's the issue with that? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to load my imageview with url ( using picasso ) received from api call, so the onCreateView is returning the view, even before my imageview is being loaded

Answer (score 1):

`Retrofit` runs asynchronously, which means it runs separate from the UI Thread(Main thread) . Since you are awaiting for the result from `Retrofit`, which runs on a different thread, the best UI practice would be to run a `ProgressDialog` till `Retrofit` fetches the URL. Then you can dismiss the `ProgressDialog` and render the image using `Picasso`.  You can also use placeholder images while loading and onError cases with Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);
```

Coming to the answer to your question, it would really be a bad practice to wait from the Main Thread till the Network call fetches a response. The aforementioned way would be ideal.

Also,

> In which method should I make retrofit calls in fragment ?

You are free to invoke the `Retrofit` call from `onCreateView()` method, again you'd need to wait till you get a response. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated the question with progress dialog as you suggested

Comment: Now , what's the issue?

Comment: when I am debugging the app, `onCreateView` is being called even before trailers tab is being selected( it is called when I select tab2 ) and the view is returned, before the api call is receiving the data. So I am unable to load the image even with progressdialog. In fact progress dialog is showing when I select tab2.

android android-fragments retrofit

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **onViewCreated** method, I assume that you do view injection correctly inside the onCreateView method, then in OnViewCreated you can do api call and in onResponse of Retrofit call you can use the data.

Comment: No this isn't solving the issue, when I am debugging the app, the `onCreateView` is returning the view, even before the api call in `onViewCreated` is being called, so imageview is not loaded

Comment: OK, but you are doing the api call, once you do it, Retrofit works async, not in the main thread. If you get your data proparly, you can show the image in onSuccess method of Retrofit.

Comment: Please in Picasso try to add also .placeholder and one image from your drawable, so whe can see that if any problem or not.